# ZF+"there exists an amorphous set" is equiconsistent with ZF

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

I'm interested if understanding if one can prove that **ZF+"there exists an amorphous set" is equiconsistent with ZF** without assuming the Axiom of Choice (ZF is the Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory).

I read the article [Definitions of finiteness based on order properties](http://h.web.umkc.edu/halle/PapersForEveryone/Dofboop.pdf).

These definitions appear in the article:

- A set $X$ is finite if it has $n$ elements for some natural number $n$;
- A set $X$  is I-finite if every non-empty family of subsets of $X$ has a maximal (or minimal) element under inclusion;
- A set $X$ is Ia-finite if it is not the disjoint union of two non-I-finite sets;
- A set $X$ is amorphous if it is infinite (that is, it is not finite) and it is Ia-finite.

These results are cited in the article:

- Tarsky observed, without using the Axiom of Choice, that a set is finite if and only if it is I-finite;
- Levy established that if a set is I-finite then it is Ia-finite.

At page 9, at the beginning of the proof of the theorem, I read: *Working from ZF+"There exists an amorphous set" (which is equiconsistent with ZF by remarks above) we prove that...*

I don't understand why ZF+"there exists an amorphous set" is equiconsistent with ZF, can someone help me?

Comment: This is a difficult argument: it requires not only the advanced set-theoretic technique of **forcing**, but also its further elaboration via **symmetric submodels**. We can avoid the former, and greatly simplify the latter, if we look at ZF modified to allow urelements/atoms - cf. "permutation models" - but this is really just a prologue to the result you're interested in.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ok, I understand. Is there a reference that proves that ZF+"there exists an amorphous set" is equiconsistent with ZF without make any use of the Axiom of Choice? I could use it as a blackbox to be sure that this result holds